This bash script will not run in terraform
I have this piece of Terraform code to run a cli bash script to configure a cluster for me, but Terraform will not run the script. The script runs fine, with no errors outside of Terraform.
The Error I am getting is:
│ Error: local-exec provisioner error
│
│   with null_resource.aks_configure,
│   on configure_cluster.tf line 2, in resource "null_resource" "aks_configure":
│    2:   provisioner "local-exec" {
│
│ Error running command './setupcluster.sh -r R21Kubernetes-newprodenveu -l francecentral -c R21KubernetesCluster-newprodenveu -e jason.content@cority.com -d argocdnewprodenveu.reporting21.com': exec: "/bin/bash":     
│ executable file not found in %PATH%. Output:
╵

I have tried running this in PowerShell WSL and GitBash. Both give out the same error
Terraform Code:
resource "null_resource" "aks_configure" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "${path.module}/setupcluster.sh -r ${local.rg_name} -l ${local.location_for_bash_script} -c ${local.kubernetesclustername} -e ${local.letsencryptemail} -d ${local.fulldnsname}"
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c" ]
  }
  depends_on = [azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.r21_new_prod_kubernetes, azurerm_resource_group.r21_new_prod_rg  ]
  
}

Folder structure:
The folder structure is below it's basically one flat folder with everything in it, including the script.


┣ aks_nginx_ingress_helm.tf
┣ aksconnection.tf
┣ aksvnet.tf
┣ argocd_setup.tf
┣ argocd-values.yaml
┣ azure_secret_store.tpl.yaml
┣ cert-manager-setup.tf
┣ cloudflaredns.tf
┣ configure_cluster.tf
┣ createnewbackend.sh
┣ data_resource.tf
┣ deployenvcongifmap.yaml
┣ dns.tf
┣ external-secrets-setup.tf
┣ keyvault.tf
┣ kubernetes.tf
┣ kubernetesroleassignment.tf
┣ letsencrypt-issuer.tpl.yaml
┣ locals.tf
┣ nsg.tf
┣ output.tf
┣ providers.tf
┣ pushsecrettokv.tpl.yaml
┣ resourcegroup.tf
┣ setupcluster.sh
┣ sql_server.tf
┣ testingenv.conf
┗ variables.tf




Are you sure that your bash is in /bin/bash and not in /usr/bin/bash? You can type which bash on the command line to find out. Furthermore, do you need to add ${path.module}/ to the command? Maybe, it works without that prefix. Also you might not need to add the interpreter at all.

if I change the bash location to /usr/bin/bash which your right which bash shows that's where it is. If I then remove path.module I get the same error on both things.

you should also make your shell script executable by running chmod +x setupcluster.sh on the command line. This is just guessing, but it might help.

What exactly did you then add to the command? It shoild be something lile ./setupcluster.sh [...]

Also, you could change the command to command = /usr/bin/bash ./setupcluster.sh [...]

I got it working by putting in ["bash", "-c" ]

Incase anyone has this problem in the future on a windows machine with GitBash the way I got this was working was like this:
resource "null_resource" "aks_configure" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "./setupcluster.sh -r ${local.rg_name} -l ${local.location_for_bash_script} -c ${local.kubernetesclustername} -e ${local.letsencryptemail} -d ${local.fulldnsname}"
    interpreter = ["bash", "-c" ]
  }
}

